# How to display in separate sections of "tableview" several entities from "coredata"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

There are two unrelated entities in Core Data. I would like to display samples of these entities in two sections in a single `UITableView` (as well as to be able to add or remove them from `UITableView`).

How can I implement this task Using one `UIFetchedResultsController` is it even possible to do it with only one fetched results controller ?

**UPDATE**

Use 2 fetchedResultsControllers, but i have error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'

This is my implementation code:

```
-(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        Education* education = [self.fetchedResultsController1 objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = education.educationType;
    } else {
        FamilyStatus* familyStatus = [self.fetchedResultsController2 objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = familyStatus.familyStatusType;
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource -

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 1) {

        NSInteger rowsCount;
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController1 sections] objectAtIndex:0];

        if (self.isEdit) {

            rowsCount = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects] + 1;

        } else {

            rowsCount = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
        }

        return rowsCount;

    } else {

        NSInteger rowsCount;
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController2 sections] objectAtIndex:0];

        if (self.isEdit) {

            rowsCount = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects] + 1;

        } else {

            rowsCount = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
        }

        return rowsCount;

    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    static NSString* addCellIdentifier = @"CellAddButton";

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        if (indexPath.row == 0 && self.isEdit) {

            AddViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:addCellIdentifier];

            if (!cell) {
                cell = [[AddViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:addCellIdentifier];
            }

            return cell;
        }

        else {

            UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

            if (!cell) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            }

            if (self.isEdit) {

                NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row-1 inSection:0];
                [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:path];

            } else {
                [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
            }

            return cell;
        }

    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        if (indexPath.row == 0 && self.isEdit) {

            UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"aaa"];

            if (!cell) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"aaa"];
            }

            return cell;
        }

        else {

            UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"bbb"];

            if (!cell) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"bbb"];
            }

            if (self.isEdit) {

                NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row-1 inSection:0];
                [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:path];

            } else {

                [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
            }

            return cell;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use one FRC because it is tied to a single entity. But, you can use a set of FRCs, one per entity, and one per section. You would need to do some manipulation of the index  paths because each FRC will expect to be supplying data for section 0 of the table.

Comment: I have to implement 5 getters, check the section number in numberOfRowsInSection and use other methods in different ways for each section?

Comment: Or 1 reusable method and a little config, or tabs and 5 tables

Comment: Thank you. But there was an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When the section is > 0 you need to create a new fake index path with the same row but a section of 0 because the FRC doesn't know about any other sections